# Restrict the base branches that can be selected for the PR

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Is it possible to place a restriction that a PR is only opened if it has a base branch of “develop or stage”.
User should not be allowed to open a PR , if it has a base branch other than “develop or stage”.

Comment: Guess that this is not possible, you could work around this, by requiring a review for a PR. From the top of my head I would try to use github actions and/or another CI/CD-Pipeline to check if the Base Branch is stage or develop and fail the pipeline, if it is not, then the PR cannot be merged.
What is your use-case behind this? Most probably there is another "easy" solution.

Comment: I am running a CI pipeline that should only be triggered if the base branch is from develop, stage or master. 
I have added conditions in it to check for base branch. 
I wanted to add an additional check , that PR should not even be opened. This way in the opened PR section on github , we will only have PRs, that are from the stage , develop or master branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  Part of the reason that this might not be desirable is because a user may want to stage multiple pull requests that each build on the other, and one way to do that is to have the second use the first as a base branch, and the third use the second, and so on.  As each pull request is merged, the base branch will be automatically updated to the branch into which its original base was merged.

If you really want to do this anyway, or you want to specifically exclude certain branches, you can do this in your CI system by checking the base branch and failing your CI check if the base is incorrect.